# Kotlin: Convert variables to non nullable if condition is true

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What I mean is following.

Consider this code:

```
// Can be a Long or null
val data1= param1.toLongOrNull()
val data2= param2.toLongOrNull()
val dataN= paramN.toLongOrNull()

// Proceed with the action if ALL of the data are not nulls
if(notNull(data1, data2, dataN)){
    // do something with data1,2,N
}
```

`notNull()` is a utility function that accepts a list of variable arguments.
Returns true if all of the arguments are not nulls.

```
fun <T> notNull(vararg elements: T): Boolean {
    elements.forEach {
        if (it == null) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The issue I am having is that Kotlin does not know that inside the `if` block, the data1,2,N cannot be null. As a result, this fails to compile:

```
if(notNull(data1, data2, dataN)){
     data1 + data2 + dataN
     // Fail: Required Long, Found Long?
     // Operator + not allowed on nullable receiver.
}
```

On the other hand, if the variables are explicitly checked against null, then Kotlin knows this is fine and does not complain.

```
if(data1!=null && data2!=null && dataN!=null){
     data1 + data2 + dataN
}
```

It would be nice to "configure" the `notNull` method in such way, so that Kotlin knows that once it returns true, any of the passed parameters cannot be null inside the block.
Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this with contracts. I tried but can't get it to understand the varargs part. As an aside, you can do this in the body of your `notNull` function:  `elements.all { it != null }` and it can become a single expression.

Comment: This is clearer, thank you @Todd!

Comment: I did not know about Contracts up until now. Looks pretty interesting, and yes, one can use it to tell Kotlin more about a function, unfortunetely quite limited. Can't use it for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously multiple ways to skin a cat, but you could do something like this :

```
inline fun <T> doIfNotNull(elements: Array<T?>, block : (Array<T>) -> Unit) {
    val validElements = arrayListOf<T>()
    for (i in elements) {
       if (i == null) return
       validElements.add(i)
    }
    block.invoke(validElements.toArray(elements))
}
```

Using with varargs (has to be last parameter, making the receiver function first arg, which doesn't feel as nice);

```
inline fun <T> doIfNotNull(block : (Array<T>) -> Unit, vararg elements : T?) {
    val validElements = arrayListOf<T>()
    for (i in elements) {
       if (i == null) return
       validElements.add(i)
    }
    block.invoke(validElements.toArray(elements))
}
```

Example :

```
fun test() {
    val elements = arrayOf(1L, 2L, null)
    doIfNotNull(elements, {
        it.sum()
    })
}
```

Comment: What I was looking for was more something like Kotlin Contracts, nevertheless, your example is a great alternative. Thank you!

Comment: Like you, I hadn't heard of Kotlin Contracts until now.